Issue on display dateTime when reopening previous windows form
I have an issue in showing a timer when i come back tio my main form from another
the main form have the following code
public Main()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm");
}

private void GestioneSerataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    GestioneSerataForm gfor = new GestioneSerataForm();
    gfor.Show();
}

private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}

now if i click the button in order to go to GestioneSerataForm it's ok.
when i try to close GestioneSerataForm with the following code
private void GestioneSerataForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Main main = new Main();
    this.Close();
    main.Show();
}

i have System.StackOverflowException in Main.Designer related to Controls.Add(timeLabel);
how can i fix that?
My necessity is only to show the current timer and nothing else
i have tried to start and stop the timer an put it public in order to restart it in GestioneSerataForm but it doesn't work

Your Main form creates and shows a GestioneSerataForm form:
GestioneSerataForm gfor = new GestioneSerataForm();
gfor.Show();

And your GestioneSerataForm form creates and shows a Main form:
Main main = new Main();
//...
main.Show();

This would happen indefinitely, each form creating the other over and over.
Instead of creating a new Main form, supply the GestioneSerataForm form instance with a reference back to the Main form you already have.  For example:
// in GestioneSerataForm.cs
private Main _main;

public GestioneSerataForm(Main main)
{
    _main = main;
}

and:
// in Main.cs
private void GestioneSerataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    GestioneSerataForm gfor = new GestioneSerataForm(this);
    gfor.Show();
}

Note the reference to this used when calling the GestioneSerataForm constructor.
Then you can use that reference to show the original Main form instance:
private void GestioneSerataForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    _main.Show();
}

